# Windows: What happens to data in a pipe when writer process exits?

Tags: windows, pipe, broken-pipe

The setup:

- process A creates process B and correctly attaches stdin, stdout, stderr to anonymous pipes between the processes.
- process B generates a small amount of data over stdout, then terminates.
- process A was busy and didn't get a chance to read the pipe until sometime after process B terminated.

Is the small amount of data still readable by process A?